# Is a Monodroid app full java bytecode or is it native code?

Tags: java, native, xamarin.android

I would like too know what is deployed and what will run on the android device.
Is it pure end to end java byte code or are there some native librairies involved?

I mean my android 2.3 destination platform does not allow me to run native librairies.
Is this going to be a problem?

I was unable to find the definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

The Mono for Android runtime runs as a native library, which in turn runs your C# code.

We've never seen a device that doesn't allow you to run a native library, but I guess you could have a very specialized, stripped down device.

Comment: Windows Phone does not allow to run native code. You will get that possibility only in the coming version 8.